# Launch Visual Studio Code Programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm trying to launch VS Code programmatically in c#.

I need something similar to

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe", "test.txt");
```

If it could work on Windows, MacOS and Linux that's ideal, but primarily Windows.

I was trying to launch a process just called "code" since you can just type `code` in a cmd prompt or in Run and it'll launch VS Code, but couldn't figure out a way to do it.

Comment: You can launch notepad like that beause the path to the exe is in the %PATH% variable. You'll need to either add the location of code.exe to this or use the full path.

Comment: @Liam code.exe is in my %PATH% but I still can't figure out a way to launch it like notepad.exe. I was considering just using the full path but people have it installed in different places. I guess I could try and look in %PATH% and figure out the path from there.

Comment: Did you try `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("code.exe", "test.txt");` What was the result of that?

Comment: *people have it installed in different places* people also have their %PATH% setup differently. You can no more rely on this than you can the full path

Comment: @mason Yes I tried `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("code.exe", "test.txt");`. I get `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified.'`

Comment: The application you're launching VS Code from, is that a console app? Or a web app? Is it running as the same user that you're logged in as? In the same app, what happens if you run `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");` Does that contain the folder VS Code is in?

Comment: @mason From a console app, and yes the same user. Running that code does have the path to VS Code's install directory. `C:\Users\m.andrews\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin`

Comment: I'm able to reproduce your result on my machine. So that `C:\Users\m.andrews\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin` folder contains `code` (a Linux shell script) and `code.cmd` (a Windows Command prompt script). The actual code.exe is in the directory just above that one. That's a curious implementation...

Comment: @mason code is a electron app I believe. This is a common pattern for load node.js based applications

Comment: @Liam You're correct that it's an Electron app. Seems they did that pattern so a user could launch VS Code by typing `code` instead of `code.exe` on Windows, perhaps so their examples would be usable on both Windows and non-Windows machines. And I guess they then didn't want to put the directory that contains code.exe in the path since at that point it's not necessary. Makes it a little tricky to launch it programatically in a clean manner...

Comment: It's the same pattern angular uses `ng` and npm with the `npm` command, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've previously written something that invoked VS Code:

```
public static class ProcessHelper
{
    public static void Open(string app, string args)
    {
        using (Process myProcess = new Process())
        {
            myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = app;
            myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
            myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            myProcess.Start();
        }
    }

    public static void OpenVsCode(string filePath)
    {
        Open("code", filePath);
    }
}
```

So you can use it like:

```
ProcessHelper.OpenVsCode("c:\\myfile.txt");
```

Comment: I haven't tried this on Linux/MacOS TBH, but I would imagine it should work, and if it doesn't then it may be a simple case of changing a StartInfo property. I'll remove the try/catch - it was fine for the needs of the code I originally wrote, but you are right, it is not needed here.

Comment: It seems that `UseShellExecute` being `true` (which is not the default on .NET Core) is key to this working, otherwise I get "The system cannot find the file specified".  I'm not sure why that is since it seems like `%PATH%` resolution is all that's needed.  [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute?#workingdirectory) states "When `UseShellExecute` is true, ... If `WorkingDirectory` is an empty string, it is assumed that the current directory contains the executable", yet clearly that's not how it's finding it here.

Comment: I should add that when I installed Code I opted to _not_ have it added to `%PATH%`, so this code only works when executed from a `Command Prompt` where I've previously run `set PATH=%PATH%;%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin`.  I also don't have a `Code.exe` subkey under either of my [`App Paths` registry keys](https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/win32/shell/app-registration) (either because that's part of the `%PATH%` install option I disabled or Code never creates one, regardless), and I would think it looking there would be the one advantage provided by enabling `UseShellExecute`.

Comment: From the [Microsoft .NET 8 documentation Remarks for CreateNoWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow?view=net-8.0#remarks):
`If the UseShellExecute property is true ... the CreateNoWindow property value is ignored and a new window is created.`
I have verified this on Windows 11. I personally opted to set `UseShellExecute` to `false` and search through the `myProcess.StartInfo.Environment["PATH"]` paths to find the full path for the `code.cmd` file.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this (Tested on Windows 10):

```
var cmdCommand = "/C code";
Process.Start("cmd", cmdCommand);
```

So what we are actually doing is opening the `cmd` app and passing in the command `code` to run in the command prompt.

**Notes**

- Make sure to include the `/C` at the beginning of the command text, otherwise it wont work
- As a commenter pointed out, you also need to make sure that the path to vscode is saved in your `%PATH%` environment variable

---

For other environments, that don't have `cmd` available, you will of course need to find some other solution

Comment: Why launch cmd just to launch code? Why not launch code directly?

Comment: @mason Because I don't know how to achieve that? maybe you can enlighten us oh great one?

Comment: @Bassie This works. I ended up doing `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd", $"/C code {MyFilePathHere}");`

Comment: I'll provide a solution when I understand what issues Mike is facing. That's irrelevant though - there should be no need to launch cmd just to launch Visual Studio Code, and it seems like a poor solution.

Comment: @mason The main issue is that `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("code", "MyPathHere");` doesn't work. .NET doesn't understand what "code" is, even if its in %PATH%.

Comment: @Bassie If launching code.exe isn't working, then we should work to understand *why* rather than trying a bandaid. It might work, that doesn't mean it's a good idea. Why launch one thing just to launch other when there is no need? It's ugly. You might think it's harmless and you're certainly entitled to your opinion. I don't agree.

Comment: Just providing a solution that works misses the point: we see solutions posted all the time that work but are more complex than they need to be, less efficient than they should be, or introduce security issues. So clearly providing a working solution is only part of the picture. Providing feedback on such solutions is an integral part of the site. People in the future will see this answer - perhaps thousands of people. I would much rather put in the effort up front to identify the best solution(s) possible rather than rushing to provide a solution. It's not meant as a personal attack on you.